# Не происходит проверки FOREIGN KEY

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, sqlite

Есть две таблицы

Таблица персонажей

```
CREATE TABLE characters (
    id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name        STRING,
    description TEXT,
    ranobe_id   INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (
        ranobe_id
    )
    REFERENCES ranobes (ranobe_id) 
);
```

Таблица книжек

```
CREATE TABLE ranobes (
    ranobe_id INTEGER      PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name      STRING (256) 
);
```

У одной книжки может быть несколько персонажей. Соответственно у персонажей есть FOREIGN KEY. Создал книжку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь создать персонажа

```
self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO characters(name, description, ranobe_id)"
                    "VALUES (?,?,?)", (name, descr, r_id,))
db.add_new_character("Персонаж1", "Главный герой", 55)
```

По - идее должна произойти ошибка так как id указываю 55, а есть только 2, но нет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. `PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;` прописано:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему не возникает ошибки?

P.S.S. прописывал команду здесь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON прописано где и когда?

Comment: @andreymal, прописывал в питоновском коде, а также в SQLiteStudio(скрин скинуть в комах не могу). После вашего сообщения попробовал прописать эту команду вместе с остальным кодом, в результате сработало. До этого отдельно прописывал в коде команду, из-за чего, видимо, она сбрасывалась.

Answer (score 1):

Вроде как официальная документация на [сайте](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) sqlite говорит следующее:

`It is not possible to enable or disable foreign key constraints in the middle of a multi-statement transaction (when SQLite is not in autocommit mode). Attempting to do so does not return an error; it simply has no effect.`

Получается, что нельзя включить/выключить поддержку внешних ключей в середине транзакции. При этом такая попытка не вернет ошибки или предупреждения, а просто будет проигнорирована. Все pragma-команды (кроме настроек журнала, так как они сохраняют свое состояние) желательно выполнять отдельными запросами в начале выполнения программы (сразу после создания соединения и до реальной работы с данными приложения), а уже потом переходить к работе с данными.